# Small voltage on GPIO output

Tags: gpio, output, wiringpi

I tried using the wiringPi GPIO library just to test some basic IO, but when I tried to output HIGH on a pin (GPIO 25) the voltage only went from 0V to 0.03V, is this normal?

If this is normal that's rather useless because I cannot bit bang anything at those levels, right?

Comment: BCM GPIO25 or pin 25? As pin 25 is the GND pin, so always 0volts. (Pin numbering is totally insane. Physical pin 22, is GPIO 6 on the pi, and GPIO 25 on the BroadCom chip.)

Comment: I am using GPIO 25 as in Broadcom numbering

Comment: So pin 22. That is definitely not normal. Output voltages should be 3.3V. Have you tried a different pins?

Comment: It seems all seems to work after a reboot

Comment: Glad you got it working.

Comment: One more thing to check, is there any load on the pin? the Pi can barely send any current on the GPIO pins (~15mA?), so anything that needs more than that is likely to drop the voltage down to near nothing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very strange but a reboot seemed to fix the issue, so if you also have it, try rebooting!

Comment: By the way, if you've resolved this issue, could you please mark this answer as such? That would be great :)